# On what real interval does the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^4)^n}$ converge

Tags: real-analysis

> On what real interval does the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^4)^n}$ converge

Also what is a closed form of this series? Does the 2nd part have something to do with definite integrals? i.e is the expression without a series an integral

Comment: Hint: For fixed $x$ this is a geometric series.

Comment: It converges for all $x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but for $x=0$, the series does not converge

Comment: @E.H.E Of course the series converges if $x=0$.

Comment: @E.H.E If you see this as a geometric series with $r=1/(1+x^4)$, then when $x=0$ the ratio is $1$. A geometric series with ratio $1$ will not converge _except_ if its initial term is $0$, which it is in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have a convergent geometric series with radius $r=\frac1{1+x^4}$ such that $\vert r\vert<1$ for $x\ne0$ (the series is convergent for $x=0$). And for $x\ne0$

$$x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^4)^n}=\frac{x^2}{1-\frac1{1+x^4}}=\frac{x^2(1+x^4)}{x^4}=\frac{1+x^4}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ratio test for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^4)^n}$
$$\dfrac{1}{(1+x^4)^{n+1}}\frac{(1+x^4)^n}{1}=\frac{1}{1+x^4}<1$$
so the series converges for  all  values of $x$ except $0$ but because there is $x^2$ in the main series, so the series becomes convergent for all values of $x$

Comment: Of course the series converges if $x=0$.

Comment: @Did, the series equal to $\frac{1+x^4}{x^2}$ then how the series converges at $x=0$

Comment: The sum of the series is what you say if $x\ne0$. If $x=0$, the sum of the series is $0$. That's how.

Comment: @Did that means the R.H.S is not equal to L.H.S

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Which RHS? Which LHS? Related to the point, how? If you fancy to make yourself understandable, please do so.

Comment: @Did ok , Now I know I was wrong.thanks